# generated pulse with delay time before it generated

Tags: gpio, python, pigpio

[image]

I want to generate about 16 square wave with delay time initial as the following figure .It mean each pulse generated must delay with a value of delay time before it generated with frequency about 40khz.

Comment: You are not really explaining what you want to do.  Your request is too vague.  From what I have gleaned from your earlier questions it is possible to do what you want.  It will need effort on your part though.  I suggest you start experimenting to see how waves work.  I also suggest you'll need to draw out on paper what you want to happen.  Clue - you probably want to construct a wave 50µs long and repeat that wave.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your recommend, @joan. Acctually I'm have chaotised to resolve this probem. I have used piscope to observe behavior of waveform how when I change duty cycle on set(pin, dc) function that you guided me but it seems not accurately as things I want. I can't observe when pulse start generated and to must delay it how? Can I observe all pulses generated on GPIO in realtime by piscope? acctually I'm not still understand how set(pin,dc)function operate as https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54859/can-any-library-generate-25-square-wave-40khz-on-gpio-pin-of-raspberry-pi-2-mode/54992?noredirect=1#comment83312_54992

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.